# Why doesn't all my controls show?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I'm having problem getting controls to show-up as I want them to. I'm a beginner programmer and very much so when it comes to forms, so any help is appreciated.

```
public void CreateCard(Card card)
{
    CardGUI topCard = new CardGUI(card);

    topCard.Location = new Point(50, 50);

    aPanel.Controls.Add(topCard);

    DrawPlacement(topCard);
}

public void DrawPlacement(CardGUI cardGui)
{
    cardGui.Location = new Point(a, b);

    a += 18; // Space the cards

    // Put the cards on a new line after half have been laid out.
    counter++;
    if (counter == 26)
    {
        a = 140;
        b = 130;
    }

    this.Update();
    aPanel.Controls.Add(cardGui);

    cardGui.BringToFront();
}
```

My problem is that I want both the control added to the panel in `CreateCard`, as well as the controls added in `DrawPlacement`, to show up. But the control in `CreateCard` isn't showing up as intended. I does show up if I comment away the call to `DrawPlacement`, so I'm thinking it has to do with the `Location` property?

I've tried all kinds of stuff but nothing's worked so far.

Comment: where do you define a and b?

Comment: They are defined globally. Made it easier to reset them for when I start a new deck (I thought).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object of type `CardGUI` that you add in `DrawPlacement` is the same as the one added in `CreateCard` so adding it does nothing.

If you want 2 times the same object at the same position you should create another `CardGUI` that look exactly like the firs one in `DrawPlacement` instead of manipulating the original object.

```
    public void CreateCard(Card card)
    {
        CardGUI topCard = new CardGUI(card);

        topCard.Location = new Point(50, 50);

        aPanel.Controls.Add(topCard);

        DrawPlacement(card);
    }

    public void DrawPlacement(Card card)
    {
        CardGUI cardGui = new CardGUI(card);
        cardGui.Location = new Point(a, b);

        a += 18; // Space the cards

        // Put the cards on a new line after half have been laid out.
        counter++;
        if (counter == 26)
        {
            a = 140;
            b = 130;
        }

        this.Update();
        aPanel.Controls.Add(cardGui);

        cardGui.BringToFront();
    }
```

Comment: No card should be in the same location. The first card should represent the deck and should be laid out in CreateCard at a location to the left of the Panel. Then, although not properly incorporated yet, cards should be drawn from deck and placed to the right of the deck, one by one with an offset (a += 18), until the deck is empty. This last part is working, it's showing the "deck" that isn't working.

But I've gotten somewhere now with the changes you gave me, I think I'll be able to get it working now, thanks :)

Comment: We are missing some code here, you should show more of what you did or explain your problem better. The `CreateCard` method in your original question Create **one** card object and place it somewhere under `aPanel` and there is no code to build a deck or place anything at another position than `a,b` (The part where you set `50,50` is useless as it is replaced later)

Comment: You've already helped me solve my current problem. But the first control that's being placed at (50,50) represents the deck and only the top card need to be seen. This was the one I couldn't see, which I can now with your changes. I only need one control there, so although I'm not sure if it's working, I also added a aPanel.Controls.Remove(topCard) before adding one. Atleast it's not giving an error. So yes, in my original code 50,50 was useless, that was why I couldn't see the control.